# Excercise: Fill vectors with integers in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Can someone help me with this excercise?

Describe an algorithm in C/C++ which:

1. Defines 2 vectors: first named **a** which contains 1000 integers and second one **b** which contains 500 integers
2. edit vector **a** by inserting in every position a value read from standard input. It is assumed that a maximum of 500 values are positive numbers.
3. after point 2, edit vector **b** inserting many 1 as many positive numbers are there in the vector **a**. Remaining portions of vector **b** must contain the value 0.

This:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    int A[1000], B[1000]; int i; 
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++) { 
        cout<<"Initialising vector A: "; 
        cin>>A[i]; 
    } 
    int j; 
    for(i=0,j=999;i<1000;i++,j--)
         B[j]=A[i]; 
    cout<<"Vector B is: "; 
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++) 
        cout<<B[i]<<"\t";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

is a similar excercise I did with different requests, but now I don't know how to edit it to fit the new requirements.

Comment: Please provide a link to the specification of that C/C++ language! Until then there are just the two **different** languages C and C++! Your code is not C!

Comment: @Hyperion  Are you going to enter manually all 1000 elements of the array A?:)

Comment: This question is quite easy considering the code you already have, just make the vector B with 500 integers and after you parse A, compare with 0 and then fill the matrix and increase a counter if positive. Take care not to go outside bound of vector B.

Comment: @Hyperion You do not check whether an element of the array A is positive and you must assign 1(s) to the array B.

Comment: @Puck can you help me with modified code? For Vlad: the code refers to another excercise which is similar and didn't check if numbers where positive

Comment: Don't solve problems by modifying existing code, write new code instead. Copy-and-paste programming is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers!

Comment: @Olaf:Most learners aren't familiar with the term "magic numbers". The concrete advice to give is: "Use constants, such as  `const int size_A = 1000;`. If this size ever change, you only need to update that one line."

Comment: @MSalters: There is something called "search provider" with google being the most popular. Maybe I expect too much if I think even a beginner should be able to search for an unknown term. Maybe they are more common in C, too because that language has no symbolic constants except for _enum-constants_.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a loop like this

```
int B[500] = {};

//...

int n = 0; 
for ( int i = 0, i < 1000 ; i++ )
{
    if ( A[i] > 0 ) B[n++] = 1; 
}

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) cout << B[i] << ' ';
cout << endl;
```